# Как исправить конфигурацию при сбитом языке ввода логина и пароля?

Tags: ubuntu, загрузка, клавиатура, локаль

Добрый вечер!

История такая — правил файл `/usr/share/X11/xkb`, поменял местами «ru» с «en», ребут, теперь при загрузке английский язык отсутствует, а логин и пароль на английском. Как при загрузке прервать загрузку графической оболочки для того, чтобы подправить конфиг?